# Почему объект дергается?

Tags: unity3d, 2d

объект двигается до положенного места, но когда дойдет до нужной точки, начинает дергаться (менять координаты примерно в тысячных долях)

```
pos = go3.transform.position + new Vector3(1.45f, 0, -1.2f);

if (go1.transform.position == new Vector3(3, 1, 0))
    {
        go2.SetActive(true);
        if (go2.transform.position != vect)
        {
            Vector3 delta = go2.transform.position - pos;
            delta.Normalize();
            go2.transform.position = go2.transform.position - (delta * speed 
* Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (go2.transform.position == (pos))
        {
            go2.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, 
new Vector3(2.01f, -0.33f, -2), .1f);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вот по этому стоит давать переменным нормальные названия. Или переименуйте переменные, что бы можно было понять для чего они, или покажите больше кода что бы было видно где они объявлены, и какие значения имеют

Comment: а ваш объект случайно не упирается во что то ?

Comment: @Andrey Нет, он ни во что не упирается

Comment: @SeeSharp все go имеют тип GameObject, a pos это Vector3

Comment: и весь этот код в Update ?

Comment: @Andey, да, в Update(), кроме первой строки она в Start()

Comment: могу предположить что он продолжает заходить в условие с Vector3.MoveTowards(). И бесконечно пытается дойти до точки

Comment: @Andrey, скорее всего так и происходит, как это исправить?

Comment: вам нужно добавить проверку. Дошел ли ваш объект к другому объекту.Если да. то не пускать его больше в условия с передвижением.

Comment: @Andrey, он не проходит проверку, так как его координаты не стабильны, возможно ли как-то округлить координаты?

Comment: Можете попробовать Vector3.Distance()   для проверки.

Comment: @ДмитрийФомичёв, что значит "координаты вектора нестабильны"? Вы можете скинуть **весь** код, а не "ну эта строка у меня в start, другие в update" - это просто не дело и вникать в это трудно.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется основная ваша проблема в подобных проверках:

```
if (go1.transform.position == new Vector3(3, 1, 0)) {}
```

Подобное лучше не делать. Вы оперируете с комплексными числами и они все на базе float. Если вы сравниваете между собой float то делать это рекомендуется вот так:

```
if (Mathf.Abs(a - b) < float.Epsilon){}
```

или так

```
if (Mathf.Approximately(a, b)){}
```

Почему? Из-за того что при расчете с флоатами накапливается погрешность, нет никакой уверенности что после вычислений вы получите число равное целому.

Чтобы сравнить две позиции в пространстве делайте это через расчет на сколько одна удалена от другой

```
Vector3 dis = go1.transform.position - new Vector3(3, 1, 0);
if (dis.sqrMagnitude < float.Epsilon) {}
```

В первой строке считаем разницу между позициями, это будет вектор. Во второй проверяем на сколько велико расстояние. `float.Epsilon` это минимальное расстояние которое используют для сравнения у `float` для сравнения близкого к нулю. Берем в расчетах `dis.sqrMagnitude` потому что квадрат длины считается быстрее, не надо смотреть на знак, квадрат всегда положительный а значение квадрата при малых величинах можно принебречь. Можете ввсти минимальное допустимое отклонение при котором считать что мы достигли позиции, в таком случае при сравнении не забудьте возвести его в квадрат.

Comment: Есть какая-то причина не использовать `Mathf.Approximately`?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker - вполне можно использовать для флоатов вместо `(Mathf.Abs(a - b) < float.Epsilon))`. Если честно мне она на глаза раньше не попадалась: "век живи, век учись". Для векторов вроде нет похожих функций?

Comment: Она только для флоатов есть, но на ее основе можно написать любое расширение. Я бы добавил информацию о нем в ваш ответ - но это уже дело ваше. Ну а вообще плюс ответу за более глубокое объяснение сравнения чисел с плавающей точкой ;)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker добавил)